# How to "turn on" the Laravel informative stack trace?

Tags: debugging, laravel-4

In the book "Getting started with Laravel4" it says that if you type in an invalid URL, Laravel will throw a `NotFoundHttpException` and display a stack trace.

However, when I use Laravel and type in an invalid URL I simply get a message says:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Any advice on this is appreciated.

Comment: go to config/app.php then set 'debug' to 'true', apparently Laravel 4.1 set the default to false.

Comment: Thanks, if you paste that in an answer, I will select it. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Laravel is set to be in the `production` environment. Instead of changing the default `debug` value for `production` you should set the environment for your machine as the `local` environment.

To set your machine as the `local` environment, open `bootstrap/start.php` and add your computer's hostname to:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('your-machine-name'),

));
```

To find your machine's name, run `hostname` from the command line.

Answer (score 3):

Go to **config/app.php** then set '*debug*' to '*true*', apparently Laravel 4.1 set the default to false.

Answer (score 1):

If you already edited the bootstrap/start.php file and still the stack trace isn't showing up, then the problem maybe with apache, try adding `Options All` and `AllowOverride All`.

**Example:**

**1)** Find your hostname. In bootstrap/start.php type:

```
die(gethostname());
```

reload the page and the hostname should appear.

**2)** Edit the bootstrap/start.php and add your hostname

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
  'local' => array('machine-hostname'),
));
```

**3)** Check your apache vhost file, it should be something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/<project-folder>"
    ServerName <example.com>
    RewriteEngine On
    <Directory "/var/www/html/<project-folder>">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 4.2

find the app config for your location.
change debug to true.

So for your server settings it's in app/config/app.php

```
'debug' => true,
```

But if you have setup your local setup correct then the setting is in 
app/config/local/app.php